# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I need to save data on `database` `MySql`

This is the code:

```
private void uploadMultipart(final String imageData,final String titolo,final String sottotitolo,final String data) {
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
               // hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {


                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Aggiunto ai preferiti!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {

                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("url", imageData);
                params.put("titolo", titolo);
                params.put("sottotitolo", sottotitolo);
                params.put("data", data);
                params.put("id", id);


                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

but with this code I get this `exception`:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Can you also post the Response which you are trying to parse?

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body.string())

Answer (score 0):

Here your using jsonArray to jsonObject

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

Instead, Use like this

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
```

Comment: boolean error = json.getBoolean("error");
 error is underline in red

Comment: Share your response json

Comment: Register Response:  
                                                                                                             []

Comment: The response is JsonArray so you have to parse the response string as JsonArray.Try the above code

Answer (score 0):

On your code where you have written JSONObject you are passing a JSON Array means your response is in array type.
write JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response) now you can access this array

For more conformation please make a comment I'll help you for sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your response String from the onResponse(String response) method is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject (enclosed in [] brackets instead of {}), hence when you try to parse and convert it to JSONObject you get an error.

Change the `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);` line to `JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(response);` - this should fix the issue.